# MySQL Searching for nearest less than numerical value

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL, and I can't seem to find this answered anywhere else.  I'm working on a project that requires me to convert between two different grids, which has been fairly straightforward in Excel.  I have 2 tables of these forms (filled in first few rows for reference):

```
JDAY   TL1   TL2   TL3
1.5    148.2 147.3 146.4
2.5     150.2 150.1 150.0
3.5    151.1 150.7 150.3

Layer  Elevation
2      150.9
3      149.9
4      148.9
5      147.9
6      146.9
7      145.9
```

In Table1, the values under TL1, TL2, TL3 are elevations that will correspond to the Elevation column in Table2.  I want to output a view like this:

```
JDAY   TL1   TL2   TL3
1.5    5     6     7
2.5    3     3     3
3.5    2     3     3
```

I need to search for the nearest less than elevation in Table2 for each value in Table1, and ouput the corresponding Layer number.  I'm not sure how to do this since the elevations aren't exact matches.  This works well using the vlookup() function in Excel.  Another thing to note is that this is a small piece of the data...there are actually 15 TL columns and 365 JDAY values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the small number of rows involved the following could work:

```
SELECT A.JDAY,
       (select max(layer) from table2 where elevation<=A.tl1) as tl1,
       (select max(layer) from table2 where elevation<=A.tl2) as tl2,
       (select max(layer) from table2 where elevation<=A.tl3) as tl3,
       ...
FROM table1 AS A
```

Comment: Actually, yeah, this does make more sense. I was trying to articulate this approach into a query but I was forgetting you can just do subqueries in the SELECT clause, rather than having to join onto them. +1 for beating me to it.

Comment: I think this should work, except the MAX(Layer) should be MIN(Layer) (Layer number increases with decreasing Elevation).

Answer (score 2):

It'll be ugly, but something like this might do:

```
SELECT JDAY, MAX(TL1) AS tl1, MAX(TL2) AS tl2, ...
FROM (
    SELECT JDAY, othertable.Layer AS TL1, othertable.Layer AS TL2, etc...
    FROM maintable
    INNER JOIN othertable AS tl1 ON maintable.TL1 < othertable.TL1
    INNER JOIN othertable AS tl2 ON maintable.TL2 < othertable.TL2
    etc...
) AS subquery
```

basically, the inner query gets all joined records where the othertable elevations are LESS than the maintable's. Then the other query selects the MAX() of each field, which should be the values you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see any need to wrap it in a subquery; `MAX(othertable.Layer) AS TL1` should work fine. Possibly want `LEFT JOIN`s rather than inner ones, but it depends on the data. Also, you need a `GROUP BY JDAY` in there at the bottom.

Comment: yeah, max could go in the inner query, just playing it safe in case the real data looks different from what the op's sample is like.

Comment: I can't think what condition you'd catch by doing that and depending on how many records there are in othertable that subquery could get very big - especialy with 15 joins. Is there a potential edge case in the data I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your table1 should probably be normalised a bit:

```
create table measurements (
  jday date not null,
  measure varchar(5) not null,
  value decimal(6,2) not null,
  primary key (jday, measure)
);
```

So your dataset would be represented as:

```
jday       measure value
2012-05-01 TL1      148.2
2012-05-01 TL2      147.3
2012-05-01 TL3      146.4
...
```

(I assume that your JDAY column holds a date?)

Now, for your question, since you're using MySql, you can combine orderby, group by and subselects to get the result you're after. There are other ways to arrive at the same result, but I think this is fairly readable:

```
select * from (
  select m.*
  from measurements m
  join layers l
  where l.elevation <= m.value
  order by l.elevation desc ) x
group by jday, measure
order by jday, measure
```